# How do I let memory array return the actual length of the value?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays

I want to create a fixed array(`w*h`), `w*h`is the maximum size, and when the condition meet(`checkOwner(_temp) == msg.sender`), the data(`_temp`) will store into the `_array`.

My question is if only few conditions meet, `_array.length` will still return `w*h`.

How do I let `_array` return the actual length of the value?

```
function Test(uint256 w, uint256 h) external {
    uint256[] memory _array = new uint[](w*h);
    uint _count = 0;
    for(uint j = 0; j<h; j++){
        uint256 _temp = ..... // do the calculation 

        // Call checkOwner function to check the owner
        if(checkOwner(_temp) == msg.sender){
            _array[_count] = _temp;
            _count ++;
        }
    }

    if(_array.length == w*h){
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an array as `uint256[] memory _array = new uint[](w*h);`, its size if fixed to be w*h. When you add elements to an array, you are merely changing the value of the item at that index, and not the size of the array itself. In the code you had mentioned, `_count` is the number of items that's been updated. You can use that value for your usecases. Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: Thanks, I just find this answer few minutes ago. Haha